# Does a US citizen and college student need a visa or visas for transits at Stockholm and Copenhagen?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, us-citizens

I am a college student and worried because I have never been out of the country by myself before. I will be traveling from Chicago O’Hare to London Heathrow and back to O’Hare from Heathrow. I have two two-hour layovers, on the way there at Stockholm and on the way back at Copenhagen.

Am I going to need a visa at any of these airports?

If so, how do I get one?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. What passport will you be traveling on? Both Sweden and Denmark are part of the [Schengen Area](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569), so a visa would not be required, for example, for U.S. or Canadian citizens.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm the original poster. I will be traveling on a US passport, I just renewed it in 2013. Perfectly valid as well, I've only been to Canada on it. Anna

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm the original poster. I will be traveling on a US passport, I just renewed it in 2013. Perfectly valid as well, I've only been to Canada on it.

Anna